# Como abrir arquivos com acento na ordem alfabética usando os.startfile no Python?

Tags: python, biblioteca

Olá, preciso abrir uma grande base de dados com vários nomes frequentemente, então criei um script que faz isso por mim. Porém estou enfrentando um problema, os arquivos com acento no nome estão aparecendo depois dos arquivos normais, fora da ordem. Por exemplo, no diretório 'Teste' do código abaixo que eu fiz para teste, estão os arquivos "Fabiana.pdf", "Fábio.pdf", "Fernanda.pdf" e "Francisca.pdf", nessa ordem.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Caio\\Documents\\Teste')
for file in os.listdir():
    print(file)
    os.startfile(file)
print('Arquivos abertos com sucesso')
```

O código retorna fora da ordem, com o 'Fábio.pdf' por último

```
Fabiana.pdf
Fernanda.pdf
Francisca.pdf
Fábio.pdf
Arquivos abertos com sucesso
```

E na hora de abrir os pdfs, acontece a mesma coisa, ele abre fora da ordem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Numa situação com muitos arquivos isso atrapalha bastante. Como faço para resolver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugestão mais elegante: use uma função de sort que suporte ordem lexicográfica adequada para sua nacionalidade e idioma.

```
import locale
from functools import cmp_to_key
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
...
files = os.listdir()
files.sort(key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))
...
```

Em alguns idiomas, combinações como "LL" contam como apenas um L em espanhol, ou um caractere ß vale o mesmo que "SS" em alemão, em resumo, simplesmente filtrar caracteres acentuados não é suficiente.